# Relation between complete spaces and usage of calculus

Tags: calculus, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces

I have been studying about metric spaces and completion of metric spaces. While reading into Hilbert spaces, I discovered this phrase on their Wikipedia webpage:"
Hilbert spaces are complete: there are enough limits in the space to allow the techniques of calculus to be used."

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space)

What did the writer exactly mean with there being "enough limits"? Does that mean "holes" or in-continuities of the space can be approximated by the limits to use calculus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$ are *both* "incomplete" (in an informal sense) in that there are some algebraic properties we desire which are not satisfied within these sets. For example, in $\mathbb Q$ there is no number $x$ such that $x^2 - 2=0$. In $\mathbb R$ however, there is such a number (for example, $\sqrt 2$). But in $\mathbb R$, there is no number $x$ such that $x^2 + 1=0$. We need $\mathbb C$ (or at least some complex numbers) to "fill this hole" in $\mathbb R$.

However, note that there is a significant distinction between the hole that I pointed out in $\mathbb Q$ and the hole that I pointed out in $\mathbb R$. We can approximate $\sqrt 2$ arbitrarily well using elements of $\mathbb Q$, and get a sequence whose limit *should* be $\sqrt 2$. However, we cannot get anywhere close to a real number $x$ such that $x^2 + 1=0$. Completeness of a metric space (in the formal sense) means that *everything you can get close to, you can actually hit*. Thus, every sequence that zeros in on some location actually has a limit. In other words, there are "enough" limits.

Indeed, $\mathbb Q$ is not sufficient to do much calculus. Limits are fine, but the intermediate value theorem clearly fails (consider the function $f(x)=x^2 -2$. We get $f(0)=-2$ and $f(2)=3$, yet there is not *rational* where $f(x)=0$). The mean value theorem is vital to proving many other results.

Comment: You meant intermediate value theorem, correct?

Comment: Up to the middle of the 2nd paragraph, I figured you were going to refer to algebraic closedness. If the answer actually deals with closed metric spaces (as I think it should, considering OP's question), please consider amending the 1st paragraph, and in particular lumping $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{Q}$ as informally "incomplete".

Comment: @JonathanY. But that's my entire point. $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$ are both "missing numbers" but $\sqrt 2$ is a "hole" in  $\mathbb Q$ where there should be a number, while $i$ is not a "hole" in $\mathbb R$. I find the distinction best demonstrated this way.

Comment: I don't see how algebraic closure relates to metric-space completeness, in the sense that $\mathbb{R}$ is "incomplete" because it's missing roots of polynomials over it. Put differently, why does the fact that $\sqrt{-1}\not\in\mathbb{R}$ more related to its "completeness" than, e.g., $x\in\mathbb{C}(x)\setminus\mathbb{C}$. Would we also be served by saying $\mathbb{C}$ is "incomplete" in that informal sense?